# Is there a way to run the Intel Efficiency Cores in the i7-13700KF at a lower speed than the Performance Cores & have that persist over reboots?

Tags: kernel

As The title above---I "believe" that I just "killed" an i7-12700KF by running all the cores at 4.7GHZ. Getting an i7-13700KF & don't want to repeat the same problem. Any Ideas?

I'm running Arch Linux with an Asus Tuf Gaming Z690....I know I can just shut off the Efficiency cores in the Bios, but I run BOINC on the Performance cores & want to reserve the Efficiency cores for all other work.

Comment: CPUs have had excellent thermal self-throttling for nearly 20 years. It's very very unlikely that you killed it that way.

Comment: You couldn't have done that unless your motherboard has fried your CPU after you enabled unsafe OC'ing parameters.